# In Azure, is there a way to find out which DB whitelisted IP's are actually being used?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, whitelist

We are nearing our maximum allowable whitelisted IP addresses.

We'd like to find out if any of the ones we whitelisted are no longer in use so we can reallocate that slot.

Comment: Which service are you talking about?

Comment: Maybe look in your app's logs? Or blob storage metrics (which source IPs)?

Comment: We have server and a DB white list. We really don't have an App log per se. Partners push data directly into our SQL DB using a connection string.   

Are there some logs that show either server access or DB Connections available for analysis.

Comment: Probably would've been good to clarify that you're talking about SQL Database and not VMs, in your question. Not sure what SQL Database logs (or doesn't log). Might need to consider additional database servers.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback, Dave. I updated the question per your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Didn't tested ..but here is an overview of how i think you can do this..

when you run below DMV you can get all Firewall rules

<kbd>[sys.firewall_rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn269980.aspx)</kbd>

Now you can monitor connections through

1.Sys.dm_exec_connections
2.Auditing

With approach 1 ,you will have to devise  a way to log the DMV output to table for the period required and then you can delete those IP's from firewall

With approach 2,you can enable auditing  and log only login info like below
[image]

when you explore logs now,you can see IP address of clients connected

[image]

Comment: Nice approach! I'll give it a try and report back on the results for others Thanks G!